# Greater than a date and Equal to a another date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table where the table column as following date column data

```
   Date
----------
1900-01-01
1900-01-01
1900-01-01
2013-07-25
2012-07-25
2012-07-25
2013-07-25
2012-07-25
2013-07-25
```

Can I write a Query to filter date column which is equal to 1900-01-01 or greater than 2013-1-1

Comment: Sure you can do it. You already have the pseudo-sql in your mind, just convert it to real SQL script. cheers!

Comment: But if I have feeling that It will fail some in some instances. If I filter both conditions in same query Im getting a different results to filtering the in two separate Queries and union them

Comment: So you are using multiple tables? try to post also your simplified table(s) structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I write a Query to filter date column which is **equal to 1900-01-01 or greater than 2013-1-1** ?

Yes, you can, it's pretty much *exactly* as you phrased the question.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
select something from my_table
where date = '1900-01-01'
   or date > '2013-01-01'
```

If your condition is more complex than that, you can parenthesise the clause to keep it self-contained (no precedence rules mucking up your overall condition):

```
select something from my_table
where (date = '1900-01-01' or date > '2013-01-01')
  and blah blah blah
```

Comment: Sorry guys its all good!! all your answers are correct but I just had another filter query which was playing up. If but the dates condition in parenthesis,  then it worked perfect

Comment: actually the only truly safe string format to be using in any of these conditions is 'YYYYMMDD'

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select data from Table where date=' 1900-01-01'
union all
select data from Table where date >'2013-1-1'
```

Comment: I actually have a very big query and I don't want to write it twice. That is why I was wondering if I can write in just one filter. Thanks for the response anyway

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server,You can use DATEDIFF function for comparing date values.

```
    SELECT col1,col2,.. FROM YourTable WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,date,'1900-01-01') = 0;

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT col1,col2,.. FROM YourTable WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,date,'2013-01-01') > 0;
```

Comment: this is no different than the straight version, `where t.dtCol = '1900-01-01' OR t.dtCol > '2014-05-23'` ... with one exception: the date column is now an *expression* and so and covering indices cannot be utilized. Further, the use of `union all` needlessly complicates things.